# SharePoint 2007 Search error

Tags: sharepoint

SharePoint search started failing all of a sudden, so I did some reading and performed "Reset all crawled content". Now the crawl is running fine, however, when search is performed on the site, following exception is thrown:

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x800703FA): Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {5AD0CC67-4776-4D91-B9A8-0078B0BAF32D} failed due to the following error: 800703fa. at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.QueryInfo.InitializeCanaryChecker() at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.QueryInfo.GenerateDigest(Page CurrentPage) at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.WebControls.CoreResultsWebPart.ClickLogPostdata() at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.WebControls.CoreResultsWebPart.OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
```

I came across only one post when I searched for this particular problem and I don't believe we have the same case here. http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-GB/sharepointadmin/thread/84861057-d862-464d-b5fc-888db5bd6805

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed this problem by recycling the SharePoint app pool

"have you tried turning it on and off again?" :)